# Is the required attribute supposed to work for stencil-custom-inputs inside forms?

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I am currently trying to build a custom input, which works just fine, but for some reason the **required** attribute (form validation) does not work.

```
  return ( // simplified code, <my-input>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="myinput">myinput: </label>
        <input required name="myinput" id="myinput" type="text"/>
      </div>
    );
```

When I nest my custom input inside a form tag, the form does not prevent the values from being submitted even though I set the **required** attribute. If I just copy/paste the html/jsx code from my component into the form-tag, **required** works as intended.

```
<form>
  // required not working
  <my-input></my-input> 

  <div>
    <label for="myinput">myinput: </label>
    <input required name="myinput" id="myinput" type="text"/> // required working
  </div>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Question**: Is there a specific reason why the required attribute is not working within a custominput (stencil-component) within a form-tag? Or maybe it is supposed to work and I somehow made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the web component's Shadow DOM breaks the link between the input and the form it is part of.

However an API for form-associated custom elements is in the making (see [Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-face-example)), to allow web components to behave more like native input elements in forms.

- Chrome status: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4708990554472448
- Firefox status: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1552327

Answer (score 0):

You can disable shadow dom, or add required attribute passed as @Prop property.